# ASP.net MVC.2 return multiple objects to strongly typed viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, repository, viewmodel

I am new to MVC and using the repository pattern in an attempt to select data containing two objects to return to a strongly typed viewmodel,

Im getting a bit stuck with what the best way to do this is,

The two tables are related by a customer id field, i have a repository interface set up, and a display template that is strongly typed to a viewmodel that contains properties for the Customer and a Customer Site object, all i need is to display a list of customer sites along with the relevant customer name from the customers table.

In the display template i have the following

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers.CustomerName) %>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers.Site.AddressLine1) %>
```

I have this display template working but my model is empty.

Where im getting confused is how to define this data in the interface and repository, and how to return the data to my model, to simply return my list of customers i use this in my interface

```
IQueryable<Customer> Customers { get; }
```

Then a simple LINQ select.

But as this data will contain both customers and customer sites im unsure how to define this in the interface?

Also will a LINQ join be a suitable method to return this data to my viewmodel? something like

```
var Customers =

    from c in customers

    join cs in customerSites on c equals cs.CustomerId into ps

    from p in ps

    select new { Customer = c, cs.CustomerName };
```

UPDATE=========

This is the code i am using in the view model that is stronly typed to the display template,

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryContactName { get; set; }
    public SiteViewModel Site { get; set; }
}
```

Its how to populate the model in the repository/controller with both objects to display in a list that im struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have done soem of the following steps already so please ignore if you have..

1 creat a ViewModel folder in your solution.

2 Create a base view model .... might look like this ->

> ```
> public class BaseViewModel
>     {
>         public PageProperties PageProperties { get; set; }
>         public User User { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

3  Setup a view model for your controller action maybe like so ->

> ```
> public class ProjectVM : BaseViewModel
>     {
>         public ProjectPoco project { get; set; }
>
>     }
> ```

4 In your controller get your data from your repositiory and pass it to an instance of your view model like this ->

> var contextVM = new ProjectVM();
>
> ```
>         contextVM.project = ObjectExtensions.Convert<ProjectPoco>(tbl.Single(id));
>         contextVM.PageProperties = new PageProperties
>                                        {
>                                            Heading = contextVM.project.Name,
>                                            SubHeading = "Details for" +
> ```
>
> contextVM.project.Name
>                                              };
>               return View(contextVM);

5 set your views model to be that of your view model ->

> @model
>   NerveCentre.ViewModels.ProjectVM

6 use your viewmodel to pull data out into your view ->

> @Model.project.Description

A quick and rough description of passing data to your view via a view model. hope I didnt miss anything out.

As for the data.. looking at how you have the model (Customers.Site.AddressLine1) would it not just be possible to pass the Customers from your query to your view model?

So your viewmodel might look something like..

> ```
>     public class SomeViewModel: BaseViewModel
>     {
>         public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
>
>     }
> ```

If you let us know what you are using for data access then we might be able to help more with the specifics of getting the data out of your tables and into the format you want?

Comment: @dav1dMclean, thanks for your advice, i'm using LINQ to sql for data access and my data is stored in an SQL database. Its the data access part im struggling with, Ill update the question with my viewmodel.

Comment: ahh OK, (you might want to make your view model inherit from a base.. never know when you'll need to add something site wide..).

Comment: I havn't used Linq to SQL but unless I'm mistaken.. your query will bring back an object with data from both your tables right? so Customers.CustomerName will possibly give the customer name? I dont know maybe Im old hat but I would think about a stored procedure and a class with the correct structure.. then run the sp into a list or type your new class. then just use that data as needed? I like my DA to be as simple and quick as possible (hence I don't use Linq to SQL :p) ->

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ -> look at performance tests on page.. petaPoco is a nice alternative. (not related I know just thought I make you aware in case you are not aware already :) )

Comment: @dav1dMclean, thanks again, any ideas on how i define the collection in the repository interface? i use this for one object but not sure how to define a collection that includes two objects, public IQueryable<CustomerSite> CustomerSites
        {
            get { return customerSitesTable; }
        }

Comment: So you want to return customer sites and customer ? I guess one customer has many sites or at least can have many sites.. With the little knowledge of linq to SQL I have I would say that something like var q = from c in customers from cs in customersites where c.id = 1232 select new {c, cs} - then I would imagine you get an object that has data for both the customer and the customer sites? - I don't think you need to join as doesn't linq to sql do this for you if you have defined your relationships?

Comment: @dav1dMclean, yes thats correct i want to return both sites and customers, ok understand the LINQ query now, but im still not sure what datatype i define the collection as in the repository, as normally it would be either customer or site as shown in the above comment. But obviously this is a mix of both.

Comment: LOL bit of a hack.. but you could.. set it to var to start with then use a break point to stop it after the var has been set then do a GetType() (within immediate window).. this should tell you what type it is.. then if you wanted you could change it from var to the type ?

Comment: @dav1dMclean, wont let me define it as var in the interface, i think i need a lot more reading, thanks for your help though.

Comment: Of course.. Do the query outside in your controller (it will let you use var there .. then look at the type) I do not know linq to SQL well enough to know what it returns I'm afraid so all I can suggest is the above.